# Facebook: Get facebook messages for specific Date?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I wanted to get facebook's messages not **Feeds**. I've searched about it but did not find the solution.

I have also looked into FQL for the same but didn't find any useful things.

Is it possible to get messages from facebook with specific date ? OR just messages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible you get lastest facebook messages on top of thread(conversation session) by specific time with fql API, such as

```
SELECT snippet, recent_authors, updated_time FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 AND updated_time=1364564697
```

Also, it's possible you get facebook message by specific time with API within thread. Such as

```
SELECT body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id=1774741570083 AND created_time=1348806942
```

> For your question. Yes. It's possible get facebook message from ALL
>   inbox messages by specific DATE(by DATE, not by TIME, as your
>   request). Example, get all inbox messages from **"Thu Aug 23 2012
>   00:00:00 GMT+0800 (MYT)" to "Fri Aug 24 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0800
>   (MYT)"**

```
SELECT body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) AND (created_time>=1345651200 AND created_time<1345737600)
```

> **Update**:
>
> To retrieve sender name and profile photo, you can do

```
{"query1":"SELECT author_id, body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) AND (created_time>=1345651200 AND created_time<1345737600)","query2":"SELECT id, name, pic_square FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT author_id FROM #query1)"}
```

> **Update**:
>   **HTTP GET request** example, quote the fql query, append to
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/fql?format=json&q=
>
> After that, append **&access_token=YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN** at the end:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/fql?format=json&q=%7B%22query1%22%3A%22SELECT+author_id%2C+body%2C+created_time+FROM+message+WHERE+thread_id+IN+%28SELECT+thread_id+FROM+thread+WHERE+folder_id+%3D+0%29+AND+%28created_time%3E%3D1345651200+AND+created_time%3C1345737600%29%22%2C%22query2%22%3A%22SELECT+id%2C+name%2C+pic_square+FROM+profile+WHERE+id+IN+%28SELECT+author_id+FROM+%23query1%29%22%7D&access_token=**ACCESS_TOKEN**

Comment: How can I use this for iOS ? I mean how to request to facebook ? can you post detailed code example for multi query ?

Comment: @林果皞: can you please explain how use the above query in iOS ? I am new to FQL so

Comment: @Maulik Sorry, i've no previous experience programming on iOS. However, you can test the query using official API explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%7B%22query1%22%3A%22SELECT%20author_id%2C%20body%2C%20created_time%20FROM%20message%20WHERE%20thread_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20thread_id%20FROM%20thread%20WHERE%20folder_id%20%3D%200)%20AND%20(created_time%3E%3D1345651200%20AND%20created_time%3C1345737600)%22%2C%22query2%22%3A%22SELECT%20id%2C%20name%2C%20pic_square%20FROM%20profile%20WHERE%20id%20IN%20(SELECT%20author_id%20FROM%20%23query1)%22%7D%0A